# Why is it called "store.kde.org" (KDE-Store)? It's not a store

Tags: kde, terminology

Why did people think it was a good idea to name the software distribution site for KDE "https://store.kde.org"? It's not a store. There's nothing that requires payment on there - a key requirement of FOSS - and there's no similarity to a store. It's *a fundamentally different thing*. (And that's great!)

I'd like to know more details on the decision-making process that lead to that name and how a change to it can be requested and implemented.

**Edit**: so it appears I misassociated "store" with the commonly associated meaning of "shop". Sorry; English is not my native language. Not sure whether I should delete this question or keep it for others who have the same question.

Comment: And `FOSS` != gratis

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk FOSS is by definition gratis. It's just not _only_ gratis but more than that.

Comment: That's no true at all. `GPL` for example does not prohibit selling software. See also this: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html

Comment: A user is not truly free to run a program, study and change the program, and redistribute the program with or without changes if he is _required to pay_ for it first. Whatever mechanism makes it a requirement for access to the software opposed to an optional thing makes the software unfree. Free software can be built into nonfree commercial software and there are many ways money can be given to free software projects such as donations or for distribution or pre-configuration efforts etc. Allowing free software to be sold does not make it unfree but gratis access is a requirement for the former

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Store" is a noun that has more meanings than just "a shop".

In particular, it has the meaning "a source from which things may be drawn as needed".

See, for reference, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/store